# How to tell if something is an IEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable

I've got a Type.

How can I tell if it's an `IEnumerable<>`?

These:

```
typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(memberType);
typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(memberType);
```

return false for `IEnumerable<int>`

Whereas this:

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(memberType);
```

returns true for string.

Comment: Call `memberType.GetInterfaces()`. Look at `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` for each one.

Comment: But `string` *is* an enumerable - you can iterate over its characters.

Comment: Do you have a `System.Type` or an `object` of unknown type?

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, I'm aware that it's an `IEnumerable`. But I want to find things that I specifically declare as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @ja72 `System.Type` Specifically, I have a `MemberInfo` on which I can call `.GetUnderlyingType()`.

Comment: @Luaan ...Oh, but IEnumerable<> is an interface, so it's impossible to actually create one - only to create something that implements it. Like String. So what I'm asking doesn't even really make sense. I get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection is fun; side note: keep in mind that you can implement `IEnumerable<X>` **and** `IEnumerable<Y>` (etc) on the same type, so for simplicity here I'm just reporting the first found *arbitrarily*:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(FindFirstIEnumerable(typeof(int))); // null
    Console.WriteLine(FindFirstIEnumerable(typeof(string))); // System.Char
    Console.WriteLine(FindFirstIEnumerable(typeof(Guid[]))); // System.Guid
    Console.WriteLine(FindFirstIEnumerable(typeof(IEnumerable<float>))); // System.Single
}

static Type FindFirstIEnumerable(Type type)
{
    if (type == null || !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        return null; // anything IEnumerable<T> *must* be IEnumerable
    if (type.IsInterface && type.IsGenericType
        && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    {
        return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    foreach(var iType in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (iType.IsGenericType &&
            iType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            return iType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... I found *a* way to do it...

```
private static bool IsGenericEnumerable(this [NotNull] Type type) =>
            typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || (typeof(IEnumerable<char>).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type != typeof(string))
            || typeof(IEnumerable<byte>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<sbyte>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<ushort>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<short>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<uint>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<ulong>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<long>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<float>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<double>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<decimal>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            || typeof(IEnumerable<DateTime>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

...but that's kind of horrible and I hope there's a better way.